# Is there an "idiomatic" way to make x-y movement (e.g. arrow keys) correspond to rotations in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there an "idiomatic" way to make x-y movement (e.g. arrow keys) correspond to rotations in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Intuitively the up, down, left and right of arrow keys would mean moving a $\mathbb{R}^3$ vertex to the corresponding directions. However, since $\mathbb{R}^3$ doesn't have clear "horizontal" and "vertical", but it also has depth, then I've been wondering how to "map" horizontal and vertical to $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Or is this impossible?

Comment: If you want to rotate an object that the viewer is looking at, the up arrow usually means "rotate the axis pointing towards the viewer upwards". For example if the x-axis points right, the y-axis points up, and the z-axis points towards the viewer, then pressing the up arrow should cause a rotation about the negative x-axis.

Comment: Anyway this looks like it belongs on https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: There are threedegrees of freedom for rotations. Read the [Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) Wikipedia article for details. I think that you will need **three** pairs of keys to indicate rotations.

Comment: There are three degrees of freedom, but one of those can be realized by how long the user holds down the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

For rotations about lines through the origin, you can use just the four arrow keys.

You can specify the axis of rotation using a unit direction vector

$$ \vec{V}=\langle a,b,c\rangle=\left\langle\sin(x),\cos(x)\sin(y),\sqrt{1-(\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)\sin^2(y))}\right\rangle$$

Use one arrow key, let's say '$\rightarrow$' to specify the value of $x\ge0$.

Use a second arrow key '$\leftarrow$'to specify the value of $y\ge0$.

This allows the value of $a$ to cycle between values of $-1$ and $1$, the values of $b$ to cycle between values of $-\sqrt{1-a^2}$ and $\sqrt{1-a^2} $ to express any direction $\langle a,b,\sqrt{1-(a^2+b^2)}\rangle$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Then you can use the up and down arrows to indicate the amount $\theta$ of positive or negative rotation about the axis.

To rotate about a line not passing through the origin one would first have to translate it to the origin, rotate, then do the inverse translation.